# Почему долго нет новых сборок?

Tags: поддержка, номер-сборки

Два дня назад [**@αλεχολυτ**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/u/176217/) написал комментарий, в котором упомянул текущую (на тот момент) сборку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сейчас, когда я это пишу, сборка всё ещё такая же!

Comment: что-то похожее было на mse... сейчас найду

Comment: Вот, посмотрите, может что-то там найдёте: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388764/almost-a-week-without-new-build (**английский язык**)

Comment: Сборок 2 недели может не быть, это нормально.

Answer (score 1):

В обычном режиме работы новые сборки появляются по несколько раз в день (в рабочие дни с понедельника по пятницу). В экстренных ситуациях могут появляться и на выходных. Но бывают и обратные ситуации, когда лучше ничего не трогать и жить на относительно стабильной сборке. В частности такое происходит на новый год. Могут быть и другие ситуации, которые так или иначе требуют держать код без изменений. Например, [Almost a week without new build](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388764/339911). В общем, надо ждать, надеяться и верить.

Кстати, сборка уже продвинулась, текущая rev 2023.6.20.4350**2**